# Thread safe Queue <t> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

I need to create a generic queue that can be queued my multiple producers, and de-queued by multiple consumers.

I want the system to at least try twice in case it attempts an operation during changes to the system, so if a process thread fails, The now flagged qBit is queued again, then when processed again, the thread performing that operation will know that another thread has already tried this operation once, and if it fails, ship this particular one off to a remediation queue for outside intervention.

So.... to the actual question, I realize that the state of the queue could change between contains() and a queue operation, like sockets checking is just a form of error control, not a substitution. I did t this way because two producer threads may otherwise toss an error when two of the same id (identified by GUIDs) try and queue what would otherwise be different object instances of a qBit.

The question is, is this a reasonable implementation? I cannot see it ever becoming deadlocked because all the methods would return regardless of the result of processing a qBit, and this allows me to somewhat prevent some of those..

Thoughts and or second set of eyes please?

```
public class tsQueue<t>
{
    object syncLock = new object();
    private Queue<qBit<t>> Q = new Queue<qBit<t>>();
    List<t> contents = new List<t>();

    public qBit<t> deQueue()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            qBit<t> pop =  Q.Dequeue();
            contents.Remove(pop.item);
            return pop;
        }
    }

    public void enQueue(qBit<t> push)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            contents.Add(push.item);
            Q.Enqueue(push);
        }
    }

    public bool contains(t check) {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            return contents.Contains(check);
        }
    }

    public class qBit<t>
    {
        public bool flag { get; set; }
        private t _item;
        public t item { get { return _item; } }

        public qBit(t item)
        {
            this._item = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

Comment: This looks thread safe to me.  @phoog I'd like to benchmark the solution with both.  In my experiences sometimes manually locking a non thread safe object is actually faster than using an object that is thread safe (i.e using a Queue vs a ConcurrentQueue).  But, I think the choice between using the two has to be application specific.

Comment: @phishfordead if performance is a problem, yes, one should benchmark and consider which solution is faster.  Library solutions are often slower than hand-rolled solutions; the library needs logic to deal with conditions that may be irrelevant for the use case in question.  But library code is also likely to be better tested than hand-rolled code, not to mention more thoroughly thought through.  So the benefit of better performance (if indeed benchmarking shows better performance) should be weighed against the cost of testing and debugging to ensure correctness.

Comment: Why the [non standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) camel casing of methods?

Comment: The camel casing is force of habit, I flop back and forth in languages all the time, no one ever sees the inside of that but me, so I tend to stick to what my eyes are used to reading.  Other responses are in reference to the answer and their relevance here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConcurrentQueue is a thread safe implementation that does exactly what you need. It will also definitely be faster that your own code. Use this [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,3aca362f2b1eb019) to see the source code of the ConcurrentQueue implementation.

Comment: I looked at the ConcurrentQueue<t> and there were questions I had about it, referenced here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx It made me not so certian so I was shooting for a perhaps longer hand method, but more easily peeked into. I do not think performance will be an issue, it is not extreme high performance, just has to be unquestionably reliable.